# Infinite Loop (concurrency issue?) in LinkedList

Tags: java, rest, concurrency, linked-list, queue

In some rare cases, the code below runs in an infinite loop printing "entry is null!". But the entry should *never* be null! I cannot reproduce it, but it happens from time to time. How is this possible?!?
If it helps, the code is triggered by a REST endpoint so that means there can be multiple threads calling this code. However, I still don't see how this could ever cause an infinite loop?! What am I missing?

```java
private final Queue<Event> queue = new LinkedList<>();

void addToQueue(String data) {
    // only place elements are added to the queue
    this.queue.offer(new Event(data)); 
}

public void doStuff() {
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        var entry = queue.poll();
        if (entry == null) {
            System.out.println("entry is null!"); // HOW CAN THIS LOOP INFINITELY?
        } else {
            // do sth. useful with entry
            // additional entries can be added to the queue here with `addToQueue()`
        }
    }
}

static class Event {
    final String data;
    Event(String data) { this.data = data; }
}
```

There is only 1 place where new elements are added to the queue, and the method assures that no nulls can be added to the queue.

Edit: removed `synchronized` since it is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: please post the code which adds to the queue

Comment: Could you please specify your queue addition code?

Comment: “*I added the synchronized part to try to make sure that there is no context switch…*” That’s *not* what `synchronized` does. I’m not sure whether it would really help to answer this specific question when the general problem is that you are using multi-threading without the slightest knowledge about it. It would be better when you start reading a good tutorial or book about this topic and learn on your own how to use `synchronized` correctly.

Comment: @Holger Well sry about that. I can't really change the circumstances unfortunately. I am reading about it, but atm still kind of stuck

Comment: Just a summary: `synchronized` does not prevent other threads from doing stuff. It only prevents threads from executing that code block when the same object has been passed to `synchronized(…)`. To protect specific mutable data, *all* accesses to that data must happen within such a `synchronized` block using the same mutex.

Comment: Please provide Minimal Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example if possible.
Because judging by the code you presented, there is no obvious problem, so there should be something else.

Comment: Oh, and yes, did it stop happening after you added `synchronized` block?

Comment: @Flame239 I wish I could, but I cannot even reproduce it myself. I just saw this endless loop kill one of my pods 3 times in a week. Synchronized did not help.

Comment: The conclusion to draw from my previous comment, is that `this.queue.offer(new Event(data));` must be placed in a `synchronized(queue) {…}` block as well. As said, *all* accesses to the shared mutable data must happen within such a `synchronized` block. Here, the shared data is the internal state of the `LinkedList` object, so all accesses to that object must be guarded by a `synchronized` block (and for completeness, all the `synchronized` blocks must use the same object for synchronization which comes naturally when consistently using `synchronized(queue) { … }`).